# How to run macro in PowerPoint with a left click anywhere on screen

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I copied code to create a numerical timer in PowerPoint. It's  visible but I want it to show and run when I left click anywhere on screen or when I press the downwards arrow on my keypad (go to next action - like next slide or next animation). Does someone know how?

```vb
Sub countdown()

Dim time As Date
time = Now()

Dim count As Integer
count = 30 'assuming 30 seconds

time = DateAdd("s", count, time)

Do Until time < Now()
DoEvents
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "ss")
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: To get the click action to trigger your macro, draw a rectangle atop the entire slide, assign it a click action of Run Macro - {your subroutine name]. Then give the rectangle a solid fill, 100% transparent, and no outline. For the other stuff, look up PowerPoint Event Handler in Google for ideas.

Comment: Is there a shape named "countdown" **in each slide**? `ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("countdown")` refers the shape in the active slide (view)... I can show you a way to make the above code running at each click/pressed arrow (which change the slides), but your code as it is works only if such a shape exists **in all slides**. Otherwise, it will raise an error, if such a shape will not exist in the active slide...

Answer (score 1):

As I tried explaining in my above comment, your `Sub` will not raise errors **only if there is a shape named "countdown" in all slides**!

1. You need a class able to trigger PowerPoint events. So insert a class module in the project, name it as "clsPPEvents" and paste the next code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application


Private Sub App_SlideShowNextClick(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow, ByVal nEffect As Effect) 'merge in SlideShow
    Debug.Print "SlideShowSlideShowNextClick" 'just to see that the event has been triggered...
    countdown
End Sub
```

2. Please, copy the next code in a **standard module**. It will initialize the above class to trigger events of the PowerPoint `Application`:

```
Option Explicit

Public myApp As New clsPPEvents

Sub EnableEvents()
   Set myApp.App = Application
End Sub
```

3. The above `Sub` must be called when your presentation is opening. Since, PowerPoint events are not enabled that time, you need to find a way to initialize the class. It can be done from an Add-in, which is a little more complicated, or using a `Ribbon` event (triggered when the needed presentation is open). I will show you this second way.

a. Copy the next code in the same standard module or in a new (standard) one. I usually create a new standard module named 'RibbonModule':

```
Public Sub onLoadRibbon(myRibbon As IRibbonUI)
  Debug.Print "Ribbon Loaded" 'just to see that it has been called
  EnableEvents 'initialize the events class
End Sub
```

Save the presentation and **close it**.

b. The above code must be called by Ribbon during loading time. So, you need to download 'Office RibbonX editor' (from [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/officecustomuieditorfiles.zip). Download the zip archive, extract its content in a specific folder and run `CustomUIEditor.exe`. To learn how to use it, look to the [next](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scXOixpWX6M) video. It shows how to be used in Excel ribbon, but it must be used exactly in the same way for PowerPoint.

So, copy the next XML code, in inserted `customUI14.xml` (for Office 2010 or more recent than it)

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
onLoad="onLoadRibbon" ></customUI>
```

Or the next one in `customUI.xml` for Office 2007:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"
onLoad="onLoadRibbon" ></customUI>
```

Inserting both `custom UI` the presentation will work as it should in all Office versions greater than 2007, inclusively.

Press `Validate` to check if the XML code is correct and if so, press `Save` button.

4. Of course, your `Sub` to be called must exist in a standard module:

```
Sub countdown()
 Dim time As Date: time = Now()
 Dim count As Integer: count = 10 'assuming 10 seconds

 time = DateAdd("s", count, time)

 Do Until time < Now()
    DoEvents
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "ss")
 Loop
End Sub
```

Open the presentation and see how the above solution works.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @Sander Van Beuningen Didn't you find some time to test the above answer? If tested, didn't it do what you need? Is it anything unclear?